# Create a zoomable map with c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a zoomable draggable etc. map of a really big image, the functionality should be like google maps but the map itself comes from me (it will be a galaxy picture).

So I think I have to use this components:

Frontend: http://openlayers.org/
([Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/fullScreen.html))
Backend: http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/

And connect them with each other, so the frontend will call the backend to display tiles in the current zoomlevel of the map.

I'm new to that map building thing and just want to make sure to not going in the wrong direction, so does it makes sense? Anyone did that before? Or any better ideas?

**EDIT**

Sorry, forgot that: The user should not have to install any additional stuff and it should run on an Ipad too, so I'm not able to use silverlight, flash etc. Just good old plain JS :)

Comment: I had worked on similar requirement but development platform was Silverlight. I had used "DeepEarth" (extended deep zoom) with tiles hosted on the local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with using openlayers.org for the frontend and building the backend by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on similar requirement but development platform was Silverlight. I had used "DeepEarth" (extended deep zoom) with tiles hosted on the local server.

1. [DeepEarth](http://deepearth.codeplex.com/)
2. [DeepZoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You can try using Bing Control and services which is a paid service. In trial version, you will get Bing logo in the background. [Bing Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412551.aspx)

Bing control or any such controls with tiling services are appropriate when you want real world map - cities/roads. If you just need to have a zoom in/out feature on an image you can use deepzoom.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds interesting, but I cannot use silverlight, I updated my answer. Sorry! But to the Bing Services, because I want to use my own image and not the offered maps it's not useful for me or am I wrong?